# Laravel. Построение таблицы на основе других

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Структура БД: https://dbdiagram.io/d/646682a6dca9fb07c459c154
Хочу создать команду для отработки 1 числа каждого месяца.
На данный момент у меня получилось забрать данные только через связи от клиента к услугам. Вкратце, формируется айди клиента и общая сумма по всем договорам и услугам к ним, к примеру: клиент 1 имеет счет №1 на сумму 60 000 руб. за 05 месяц.
\app\Console\Commands:

```
public function handle()
{
    $clients = Client::get();
    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        foreach ($client->with('agreement')->get() as $client_agreement) {
            foreach ($client_agreement->agreement as $agreement) {
                foreach ($agreement->with('service')->get() as $agreement_service) {
                    foreach ($agreement_service->service as $service) {
                        // DB::table('bills')->insert([
                        //     'client_id' => $client->id,
                        //     'name' => $client->agreement->service->name,
                        //     'price' => $client->agreement->service->price * $client->agreement->service->count
                        // ]);
                        $this->info($service->name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Я понимаю, что чушь написал, просто тестировал таким образом обращение.
Проблема в том, что доступ модель клиента $clients->agreement->service к услугам не имеет, только договора, а как мне тогда получить необходимую информацию?
Еще момент, что если договор создан 30 числа, счет приходит за этот месяц только для 1 дня, если в месяце 31 день, тогда сумма услуг / 31 * 2, что будет соответствовать цене услуги за 2 дня, далее проверяется за какой месяц выставляется, следующий будет иметь полную стоимость и так далее.
Но это я думаю не сложно будет через карбон решить, а вот как вытянуть правильно данные пока что в голову не дошло...

Comment: Не вариант при подписании создавать задачу (отдельную таблицу с данными для создания записи в bills), кроном слушатель, условно, каждый день отрабатывает и смотрит все задачи выполнены или нет? По-моему так проще было бы ведь при подписании все данные есть и не надо изголяться запросами. По теме запросов, если связи прописаны то через with() все данные подтягиваться должны, в т.ч. и "вложенные" связи. И не понятно, проблема то в чём? Лучший способ ищите? Подтягивайте всё с with() и будет коллекция со всеми данными, по ней циклом без запросов гулять можно

Comment: Я уже писал $clients->with('agreement')->with('service') и пытался получить сразу список услуг, но мне выдавало ошибку, что таких данных нет.

Comment: `Client::with('agreement.service')->get()` или обе -> `Client::with(['agreement', 'agreement.service'])->get()`

Comment: @InDevX `Client::with('agreement.service')` так же вернет обе связи, насколько я помню

Comment: @lezhni возможно, давно не пользовался